# Javascript: save canvas as image ==> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, canvas, io, save

I'm trying to save a google map-canvas as .png image. But I get repeatedly this error:
==> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

==> Ther error occurs when:
`ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")`
is called

I use FileSaver.js, Blob.js and canvas-toBlob.js found here:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Here is the code (note: googelmaps initializeMap function not included):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
            function initializeMap() {
                .... bla bla bla ...
            }

            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){

                var canvas = document.getElementById('SingleMapCanvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "prettyImage.png");
                }); 
            });
</script>
</head>

<body onload="initializeMap();">
    <div id="SingleMapCanvas">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag that you are mentioning in your HTML should be a 'canvas' tag instead of 'div'

```
<body onload="initializeMap();">
        <canvas id="SingleMapCanvas">
        </canvas>
</body>
```

Here is a jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JL3K9/) for the same. Hope it helps :)

Comment: whooo that worked, image gets saved but it's empty. but thats a different problem and probably another question. thanx.